# Is ...\app\User.php a (laravel) model?

Tags: php, laravel-5

All sorts of discussions say things like add this to your model and then name "User".

I assume they are referring to ...\app\User.php

But the opening lines of the file are

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
```

when I would be expecting something like

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class UserController extends Model
```

I'm probably mixing up facades with controllers, and guards with facades, and heaven knows what else, but wow Laravel has a lot of layers.

Is this User.php the stock standard model created by default on a new laravel site? (Laravel 5.2)

Comment: Yes it is a model.

Comment: I don't know enough about Laravel to know exactly if and how bad they misinterpret the Model term, but it must be one of the most abused terms in programming by now. Model is usually a shorthand for [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) and that's more like a layer than a single class. In any case, `class UserController extends Model` must be wrong because a Controller is not part of the Domain Model, but of the User Interface.

Comment: yes it's a model because the Authenticatable is a model extends from user model : class User extends Model implements

Comment: @Maxcot; check this : vendor/laravel/Foundation/Auth/User.php

Comment: So how come when I try a form model binding, and in my view say `{{ Form::model($User) }}` I get the error `Undefined variable: User (View...`